# Set callback per email in Mandrill

Tags: php, mandrill

Is it possible to set callback (webhook) per email being sent? I have two different types of webhooks needs to be triggered depending on the which one of my server email is being sent.

I can not see any parameters in `/messages/send.json` . All I see is the webhook setting page where I can hard-code my webhooks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Mandrill's [Rules Engine](http://help.mandrill.com/forums/22087471-Rules-Engine).  You'll first want to set up the webhook URLs on the Webhooks page in your account.  Don't select any events to trigger, but just save the webhook (and give it a description if you want).

Then, create a Rule for each type of event you want (send, open, click, etc), and the criteria to apply the rule (for example, you can set it to occur when a message is sent, and the sender address matches a certain pattern). For the action, select the option to send the webhook and choose the one you want to use.  In the [Example Rules](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/25142202-Example-rules), there's a section for "Create API key, sender, or domain-specific webhooks" that will show how you can do this.

Comment: This sounds impractical as I have to create 10 rules per my environments not to mentioned an API key for each env or developer..

Comment: This is also impractical for me;  my Mandrill emails might be sent from several possible creation points and the callbacks need to go to the right place.  I can happily define webhook endpoints permanently, but I need to be able to alter the webhook URL to come back to the site that sent the message.